# who is Audulomi who appears in Brahmasutras?

Tags: history, rishi, brahma-sutras

What is the history of Audulomi who appears in Brahmasutras of Vyasa

Comment: His history is unknown other than what's mentioned in the Brahma sūtras and that he pre-Bādarāyaṇa ācārya. Some of his doctrine is revealed by Bādarāyaṇa in the sūtras. But the time and his mention in other scriptures isn't known.